# Preview app will not open on my MacBook Pro 2011, macOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

Tags: preview

When I double click on the preview app nothing happens. I try dragging files into preview and a message comes up saying "The application "Preview" is not open anymore".

I cannot remove the shortcut from the dock, I've tried opening from the applications folder and that doesn't work either. I've checked the activity monitor and when I search Preview under the CPU tab nothing comes up. I've tried force quitting Preview through the apple menu and by right clicking on the app.

Please help!

Comment: Presume you've rebooted the system at some point and this persists?

Comment: Have you recently altered the system in any way? Might be worth re-applying the combo updater. 
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1970